# Redux state not updating after action dispatched

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a form for users to enter their details and press submit. This is supposed to dispatch an action and update the state by `.concat()`  a class to it. Unfortunately the state isn't updating and I don't know why. If I take out `useCallBack()` or `useEffect()` from the code , the emulator freezes and I suspect infinite loops.

Redux Reducer

```
// Initialised class
import newAccount from '../../models/newAccount'

import { CREATE_ACCOUNT } from '../actions/meals'

const initialState = {
    account: [],
}
const addPerson = (state=initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case CREATE_ACCOUNT:
            const newAccount = new newAccount(
                Date.now().toString(),
                action.accountData.name, 
                action.accountData.image,
                action.accountData.email,
                action.accountData.password
            )
            return { ...state, account: state.account.concat(newAccount) }
    default: 
        return state
    }
}
export default addPerson
```

Redux action

```
export const CREATE_ACCOUNT = 'CREATE_ACCOUNT'
export const newAccount = (Id,name,image, email, password) => {
    return {type: CREATE_ACCOUNT, accountData:{
            Id: Date.now().toString(),
            name: name,
            image: image,
            email: email,
            password: password
        }
    }
}
```

The class

```
class newAccount {
    constructor( 
        id,
        name,
        image,
        email,
        password
    ){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
export default newAccount
```

The Component

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import {newAccount} from '../Store/actions/accounts'
import ImagePicker from '../Components/ImagePicker'

const AddScreen = (props) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState('')
    const email = useSelector(state => state.account.email)
    const password = useSelector(state => state.account.password)

    const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch(newAccount(Date.now(),name,selectedImage,email,password))
    },[dispatch, name, selectedImage, email, password])

    useEffect(() => { handleSubmit
        props.navigation.setParams({handleSubmit: handleSubmit})
    },[handleSubmit])
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.card}>
                <ImagePicker onImageSelected={selectedImage} />
                <AddForm email={email} password={password}/>
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={name => setName(name)}
                    value={name}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

export default AddScreen

AddScreen.navigationOptions = (navigationData) => {
    const submit = navigationData.navigation.getParam('handleSubmit')
    return {
        headerTitle: 'Create Account',
        headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity  onPress={submit}>
                <Text style={styles.createOrange}>Create</Text> 
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

I really don't know why it's not updating .

Comment: did you try: `return { ...state, account: [...state.account, newAccount] }`

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you shouldn't store classes in the redux store, the store should only exists of plain objects. but if you really want to store the class:

The real problem seams to be `return { ...state, account: state.account.concat(newAccount) }`. here you concat the existing array with the new class, but that doesn't work.

your store looks like this if you do so:

```
{
  account: [{
    email: "..."
    id: "..."
    image: "..."
    name: "..."
    password: "...
  }],
}
```

so your selector (`state.account.email`) will return undefined. you can use (`state.account[0].email`)

or you can fix it by fixing the real problem:

```
return { ...state, account: newAccount }
```

also your initialState shouldn't be a an array for account as it will never be an array, it will be an `Account` class (this is why you don't get an error by what you are doing). set it to `null`.

```
const initialState = {
  account: null,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why this doesn't work. Just want to give you an advice to make it more simple and clearer (from my point of view):

You can drop side effects like `useEffect`. To achieve this just move local state to redux state and then you will be able to just dispatch the action from your `navigationOptions` component. It could look like:

```
const AddScreen = () => {
  const name = useSelector(...);
  ...
  const password = useSelector(...);

  // trigger action on something changes, for instance like that:
  const onChange = (key, value) = dispatch(newAccountChange({[key]: value}))

  // return tree of components
}

export const submitNewAccount = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { id, name, ... } = getState().account;
    dispatch(newAccount(id, name, ...));
  };
}

AddScreen.navigationOptions = (navigationData) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const submit = dispatch(submitNewAccount());
  ...
}
```

I used `redux-thunk` in this example.

I believe, this approach will give you more flexible way to debug and extend your business logic.

Comment: The 'const dispatch = useDispatch()' gives an invalid hook call error since it isn't in a functional component it's in the navigationOptions. How would I solve this using your example

Comment: Oh, I see, `navigationOptions` is just a function, not a component. Ok, then you can define `HeaderRight` component with hooks and use just like: `navigationOptions  = ()=> ({headerRight: ()=> <HeaderRight />})` And `HeaderRight`: `const HeaderRight = ()=> { const dispatch = useDispatch();... }`